# Sphinx documentation showing double-colon in fields

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, numpydoc

I am developing documentation for a package and when I build the sphinx docs I'm getting double colons

[image: double colons]

for all of the fields for every function definition.

I am using the numpydoc style for my docstrings and there are no colons in those docs to indicate where they might be coming from:

```
    """

    Function description

    Parameters
    -----------
    param1: str or list
        A description for the parameter

    Returns
    -----------
    Dictionary
        Some info about what is returned

    Examples
    -----------
        >>> output = somefunction(param1)

    """
```

Has anyone run into this before? It's worth noting that this does **not** happen to the `Examples` field. Just `Parameters`, `Returns`, and `Return Type`.

Comment: Same here, no idea why this is happening.

Comment: sphinx 6.1.3 still has the issue...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Sphinx `5.0.2`. When inspecting the HTML file, it looks like a CSS rule adds a semicolon (`::after`) using:

```
dl.field-list > dt:after {
    content: ":";
}
```

I got rid of that behavior by overriding this rule in my [custom css style](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize/custom-css.html) sheet:

```
dl.field-list > dt:after {
    content: "";
}
```

It is obviously not the best solution but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like to be a bug of some versions. I moved from Sphinx `3.5.2` to `4.4.0` and the double colons are gone.

Comment: Double colons are showing for me using `4.4.0`.